# Run executable file with arguments in python, sub process takes endless amount of time

Tags: python, subprocess

Iwant to run a .exe file in python. I have used the following code and it worked

```
exeFileNameAndPath = "someDiroctory/app.exe"
import os
os.startfile(exeFileNameAndPath)
```

This works. However I need to send and argument to the app.exe which I can not do it with startfile (I have tried it in many forms). So taking advice from the stackoverflow I have used subprocess to run the app.exe. here is the code

```
import subprocess

def run_exe_with_arguments(exe_path, arguments, timeout_seconds=100):
    try:
        # Construct the command as a list, where the first element is the executable path
        # followed by arguments (if any).
        command = [exe_path] + arguments

        # Run the command and set a timeout for the process.
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, timeout=timeout_seconds)

        # Check if the process returned an error code and handle accordingly.
        if result.returncode != 0:
            print(f"Error occurred: {result.stderr}")
        else:
            print(f"Output: {result.stdout}")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: The executable file was not found.")
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print("Error: The executable took too long to respond.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Example usage:
exeFileNameAndPath = "someDiroctory/app.exe"
arguments = ["arg1"]
run_exe_with_arguments(exeFileNameAndPath, arguments)
```

This takes more that 100 seconds (even more than 10 minutes) and does not show anything. Is there any thing that I am missing?

I also tried to run cmd, and send the app + arg as a comand, but even the following code did take endless time which I think this might also causing to the same problem.

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "Your Command Prompt Command"')
```

Comment: 1. You have to double your black slash: `"someDiroctory\\app.exe"`, 2. Have you tried to run the same command from the terminal with the same arguments?

Comment: Does this code not give any output at all? And are you expecting the exe to close within 100 seconds on its own?

Comment: The app.exe (it is a simple consol app) gets an input argument e.g. "arg1", and prints in the consol  "****arg1", if you do not send arguments it prints "****". 

I can run it on the command prompt by just simply writing "someDiroctory\app.exe arg1", if you mean this. 


It doesnt give me any output, that is the problem. It just takes endless time like it is in a forever loop or something.

Comment: I can’t test right now but I’ll try it out later, I’ll comment again if I manage to figure out the issue

Comment: I appreciate it. About the backslash, I always use the forward slash, I will edit the original question to not confuse others. Thanks for that

Comment: Are you running this from inside a GUI, or from a command line?

Comment: I run it in vs code -> Jupiter notebook

Comment: I was suspicious when I read your comment, and I use the Python console to run the code, and it worked there. Why VScode>Jupiter blocking subprocess? Do you know any way to get around this issue?

Comment: I tested it on my machine in both vscode and pycharm (I don't have Jupiter) and it seems to work so I could be something to do with your installation. Have you tried ctrl+c to stop the program, and does that give a traceback. It would be very helpful to get some kind of traceback since I can't think of any other way to test this really

Comment: This might be true that the problem lies inside the installation, I have also checked in .py file and it worked. There might be a setting in the Jupyter that I have not set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the code runs correctly in the Python console but encountered issues when running it in VSCode (Jupyter). It seems something in my installation is blocking VSCode (Jupyter) from using subprocess. Notably, the code runs fine in VSCode's regular Python environment when working with .py files.
**Note that I couldn't find the solution why I can not execute it in VSCode (Jupyter) yet.**

To clarify, by VSCode (Jupyter), I mean that I have opened a .ipynb file in VSCode and written code within that file using the Jupyter Notebook interface. On the other hand, VSCode's regular Python environment refers to working with .py files in VSCode, where the code executes using the standard Python interpreter.

Credit goes to @Cmd858 and @Tim Robert for their assistance.

Comment: Yes you are right., I have just updated the post. I have also clarified what I am referring when I say VsCode(Jupyter),